# Why does XmlReader check for illegal characters when settings tell otherwise?

Tags: c#, xml, unicode, mono, escaping

I work on Unity3d project, which uses Mono implementation of .NET platform. I use XmlReader on XML that contains high & low unicode surrogates, for example:

```
<node data="&#55357;&#56845; ...
                    ^ Here's the symbol referenced in exception
```

XML has no  tag — which is bad, but can't be changed for backward compatibility. (For the same reason the whole xml can be hardly changed at all). So, it is my understanding that XmlReader assumes XML version 1.0, in which unicode surrogates are illegal characters.

However, I don't want XmlReader to check for legality of characters, and use CheckCharacter settings to tell him not to do it. Here's the code:

```
    public void Load(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        using (var reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stream))
        {
            reader.Settings.CheckCharacters = false;
            m_Document = XDocument.Load(reader); // Here goes exception
        }
    }
```

However, I still get this exception:

```
XmlException: Referenced character was not allowed in XML. Normalization is True, checkCharacters = True  Line 1, position 580.
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadCharacterReference ()
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadAttributeValueTokens (Int32 dummyQuoteChar)
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadAttributes (Boolean isXmlDecl)
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadStartTag ()
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadContent ()
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read ()
System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read ()
Mono.Xml.XmlFilterReader.Read ()
System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement ()
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XElement.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader r, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ReadContent (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.LoadCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.Xml.XmlReader reader)

(My code that you can see above)
```

What is really strange is that it says "checkCharacters = True", when I just set it to false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Incidentally surrogates are still non-well-formed in XML 1.1, so changing that wouldn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass settings to [XmlReader.Create(Stream, XmlReaderSEttings)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162473.aspx) function if you want to customize settings.

The [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756wd7zs.aspx) function you use will use default settings as covered in Remarks section:

> An XmlReaderSettings object with default settings is used to create the reader. If you wish to specify the features to support on the created reader, use the overload that takes an XmlReaderSettings object as one of its arguments, and pass in an XmlReaderSettings object with the correct settings.

Comment: Just for reference to OP:  Here is the documentation for the XmlReaderSettings Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.aspx

Comment: Thanks! That line with settings was part of legacy code — I assumed that it should have worked, and something is wrong with particular symbols.

Comment: This doesn't return XmlTextReader. How do I create XmlTextReader with settings?

Comment: @PsychoDad creating Xml readers covered in details in [Creating XML Readers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9khb6435%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) article - you need to wrap one reader with another, or you can simply call constructor.